# How would humans evolve if they began living underground?

Tags: biology, evolution, fantasy-races, underground

So I am creating a world where some humans begin to live underground and in caves under mountains but I am struggling a bit with how they might evolve. My problem is that I don't want them to just be facsimile of dwarves, so I was imagining them to have thick, rough, grey skin and to be taller and more muscular than normal humans, I guess physically more like an orc but I don't know how much sense this would make. My thoughts on it are that they would be big and muscular because of the demanding physical work of carving tunnels from the rock. Over the generations, their skin would become grey from being away from natural light for so long and I imagine that their skin would become thicker to cope with the abundant sharp and jagged rock edges. It wouldn't be constant darkness as they would light their settlements so I don't see them losing their eyes or sense of sight like troglodytes, but I imagine that they would have an innate night vision as the workspaces when expanding settlements would be fairly dark.

I don't have a time frame for these changes but I imagine it would happen over several millennia and it would also be assisted by magic as there are many sources in the deep places. Does this sound like a reasonable evolution? Is there anything else that might change to further differentiate them from standard humans?

Comment: Well, the most amazing attribute that would differentiate them from standard humans is that they don't have to eat. Those individuals who were not able to adapt to a food-less life would die, as there is no food in caves under mountains. Other than that, magic can make anything happen, including ensuring the survival of a tiny population of humans. (Tiny because in reality there are precious few caves, and extremely few places in caves where a human can stand upright.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what is their tech level, how much light and food do the caves have. they will not be getting big with limited food supply, this is the classic conditions for island dwarfism. keep in mine a few millennia is barely enough time to change human skin color. Alos if they have better night vision expect poorer color vision.

Comment: Look at cave fish.  They grow *pale* not gray, for instance.  Also blind

Comment: The big question is, at what point did the creatures' ancestors start living underground? Was it at stone-age level i.e. the "caveman" extending to its extreme? Or was it an earlier point - e.g. going back to the primordial slime? Was there already huge underground networks of caves throughout the land that they could live in? Why didn't they come out into the sunlight where food would have been way more plentiful? What exactly are their food sources? All of this, especially the first question is very important to coming up with an answer.

Comment: Worth pointing out that "several millennia" is a very, very short timescale for evolution, particularly for humans, who have a habit of making our environment adapt to us, rather than the other way around.

Comment: This has been studied, multiple cave systems. Key word troglobite. Do your research please. While not specific to humans the same patterns happen again and again to populations living in caves, assuming they can find food.

Answer (score 5):

You scenario poses a LOT of problems just living there without worrying about evolving.

We get vitamin D from sunlight amongst other things, so you need a good source of that. A good source of food that supplies all our dietary needs. Heating etc,.

Given all that and a few millenia evolution wouldn't have time to do much at all, you'd get paler skin and probably not much else. I would think sexual selection would be more of a mechanism for change than evolution.

Answer (score 1):

There is food under mountains and it caves- but it comes from either the surface. (Swept in plant material, fish etc. via streams). Or it comes from parts of the mountain (coal, oil) which once were part of the surface.
Or it can be created using the temperature differential (aka. geothermal) - which implies and needs a high-tech cilization, you can not grow plants near a lava stream.
Plantlife could in theory also thrive near a natural radioactive reactor.

The first thing that would evolve is a diggestion similar to cows or a hunt for animals that can produce Vitamin B. The skin would go completely white (no pigments needed, ever again).
Sight would degrade - and sound echo location would improve. Other senses might evolve too (for example air pressure differential detection via sensitive hairs).

The rest really depends on how much technology is available or re-developed.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how much assistance they have in the form of tools/magic. There's really not much need to adapt to your environment when you can adapt your environment to you. However, given enough time/"magic-guided evolution" they'd probably become paler and blinder no matter what, and if they adapt to living by torchlight they might develop some sort of low-light vision similar to that of nocturnal animals like cats instead of going totally blind. They'd develop other senses more useful underground, like pressure sensitivity and echolocation or some sort of nerve endings sensitive to ground vibrations that would help them orient in low-light enclosed places.

One important part of traversing caves is squeezing into tight spaces, and even more important than that is squeezing *out of* tight spaces, so if any morphology changes happened I'd bet on them becoming smaller, leaner and more flexible, rather than bigger and bulkier. I also doubt having to dig would make them stronger; when carving tunnels *through rock* the hardest part isn't "not being strong enough", the hardest part is *the rock*. To break a hard rock apart you need even harder tools that nowadays are made with composite materials and are motorized, so unless they have access to adamantine/mithril/unobtainium tools (or laser/magic cutters) they aren't going to be carving tunnels on hard rock anytime soon, and if they have access to those materials or they're tunneling through softer rocks they won't really need to be much stronger than your average human (humans are perfectly capable of carving soft rock, see [Derinkuyu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derinkuyu_underground_city), an underground city built somewhere around the 8th century BCE). You can apply a lot of concentrated force with a pickaxe or hammer and chisel, no need to become "biologically stronger by default" (for lack of a better phrase), you just need harder materials to make your tools out of and, maybe, better endurance.

As other answers commented, their diet would have to change pretty drastically too. They'd probably have to synthesize their own vitamin D or get it from somewhere else. But by default there's not much of what we'd consider "food" in caves, there's some living organisms in there but not nearly enough to support a whole hominid civilization; whether this is solved by their organism or by their society (they might develop farming techniques for some kind of fungus or lichen, for example) it is something they will have to adapt to.

Air could pose a problem too. As cave dwellers they'd have to adapt to an atmosphere that by default is lower in O2 and higher in CO2 than what we're used to. Air underground fluctuates wildly in composition too, and it doesn't circulate easily, so any concentration of people living underground would either engineer air conducts to recirculate surface air (which would make them dependant on surface air and, therefore, at risk of asphixiating if a cave-in happens or if they hit a pocket of underground gas) or become resistant to hypoxia/anoxia situations like naked mole rats, which live in underground colonies and whose metabolisms slow down so they don't asphixiate when there's little oxygen.

TL;DR: Overall, depends on their tech level. Basic mutations like losing pigmentation are likely to happen in any case, other stuff depends a lot.